# VB.Net add count for each

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that search for the count of multiple words in a text file.

```
Dim textlog = File.ReadAllText("D:\1.txt")
Dim count = Regex.Matches(textlog, "test1").Count
Dim count1 = Regex.Matches(textlog, "test2").Count

Label1.Text = (count)
Label4.Text = (count1)
```

It's working fine, but I want to pass the words as parameter to the function.
And I have done this:

```
Dim values As String

values = words

Dim wordlist As String() = Nothing

wordlist = values.Split(",")

Dim w As String

For Each w In wordlist
    '''''''
    ' search function here
    '''''''
Next w
```

Now I want to count them, knowing that the words are dynamic, meaning put as many words as you want. In another words, how can I know how many words are being input and find the count of them, I don't know how to return them via the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that `regEx` is the most effective way to do such a thing, but here is a solution based on your own code:

```
Function CountWords(FileName as string, wordlist As String()) As String(,)
    Dim ReturnValue as string(,) = new string(wordlist.Length, 2)
    Dim textlog = File.ReadAllText(FileName)
    Dim i as Integer = 0
    Foreach Word as string in wordlist
        ReturnValue(i,0) = Word
        ReturnValue(i,1) = Regex.Matches(textlog, Word).Count
        i+=1
    Next
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here, and it's been a while since my vb.net days, so there might be some mistakes. However, I believe that the concept is more important in these kind of answers.

Comment: thanks alot,but there is something wrong in line 2, new string

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: It's been a long time since my vb.net days. but since you accepted the answer, I guess you found and fixed the problem. feel free to edit my answer to fix the problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to map the words into a [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) where `TKey` is the word (String) and `TValue` is the regex count (Int32)?

```
Dim words = {"test1", "test2"}
Dim result = words.ToDictionary(Function(w) w, Function(w) Regex.Matches(textlog, w).Count)
```

If you only want to get duplicates, add the following to the end of the linq expression:

```
.Where(Function(p) p.Value > 1)
```